# How to dim the background when an alert is shown and turn #dim off when alert is closed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This my js snippet:

```
reset.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("#body").classList.add("darkenPage");
    myReset();
    alert("Reset Successful!!");
    document.querySelector("#body").classList.remove("darkenPage");
});
```

and the css part is :

```
.darkenPage {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

The browser I am using is Chrome. My the background doesn't get darker even if I try this css snippet which I found on google:

```
.darkenPage {
        height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try: Over-ride the default `alert()` function and use the same classes to  manipulate your requirement.

So that you can just call the `alert` wherever you want: and the page will dim.

```js
var originalAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(args) {
  document.querySelector("html").classList.add("darkenPage");
  setTimeout(function() {
    originalAlert(args);
    document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("darkenPage");
  });

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

html.darkenPage {
  background-color: black;
}

html.darkenPage body {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
Content<br>Content<br>Content<br><br>
<button onclick="alert('Hello World')">Alert</button>
<br><br><br> Content
<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>
```

Comment: It sometimes not working. Sometimes only working once. It's informative though.

Answer (score 1):

Just do all the steps in the correct order:

```
reset.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //darken page
    document.querySelector("#body").classList.add("darkenPage");

    //display alert box - this pauses javascript execution
    alert("Reset Successful!!");

    //lighten page
    document.querySelector("#body").classList.remove("darkenPage");
});
```

if this doesn't work out correctly and you want to make sure the CSS applies first you could try to delay the alert by `setTimeout`.

```
reset.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //darken page
    document.querySelector("#body").classList.add("darkenPage");

    //make sure the dark page gets rendered before alert is displayed
    setTimeout(function(){
        //display alert box - this pauses javascript execution
        alert("Reset Successful!!");

        //lighten page
        document.querySelector("#body").classList.remove("darkenPage");
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: This works, but only once.  After clicking reset, it dims the page and then, after the alert is closed, it removes the dim. But, the next time I click reset, it just shows me the alert. CSS is not applied on nth click(n > 1). I have to refresh the page to make it work again. Why is this happening?

Comment: Don't know why this would be happening. Can't help you more with the code we got here.

Comment: Here's the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/vighnesh153/pen/BqoOYe) to the entire code. The background doesn't dim exactly how I want, but that is not the main problem. I just want to reset button to display and remove STYLE.

Comment: I also used bootstrap.min.css if you want to see all the external styles as well. And also files have relative path.